# PHP echoing HTML tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I am having a problem with some textarea things. I insert text into my database using a textarea like

```
<textarea id="e1" name="content"></textarea>
```

My php file then runs some stuff on it as shown to make HTML tags out of \n and \r:

```
$str     = $_POST['content'];
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace($order, $replace, $str));
```

and the result gets inserted into a database.
I then call the result from the database in `$content` and put that in a text area like so:

```
<textarea id="e1" name="content"><?php echo $content ?></textarea>
```

When I view that page the `<br />` tags are visible. 

An Example:

I submit this into the text area

```
Hello,
This is text.
Best Rergards,
Testificus
```

It gets processed by my php code and then is echoed into the textarea. When it is echoed into the textarea it comes out in the form:

```
Hello,<br />This is text.<br />Best Regards,<br />Testificus
```

Is there any way of having the text look like before with the `<br />` tags in action rather that being presented as text? Thanks for your help and let me know if it is not clear what I mean.

Comment: try using <?php echo strip_tags($content) ?>

Comment: Remove str_replace($order, $replace, $str). mysql_real_escape_string is enough.

Comment: @dfsq The str_replace is to convert the /n tags to <br /> tags (as the text gets emailed out in html form later)

Comment: @Dinesh That seems to just take out the tags and leave everything on one line still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right, you want to replace the newlines with the `<br />` tag? Why don't you just use `nl2br()`.

If you want to keep using your example, you have to use:

`$replace = "<br />\r\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the `\r\n`'s in the database and then when you want to output to html, simply run the text through `nl2br()` which swaps new lines for `<br>` elements. If you do it this way you don't need to worry about extra converting, it is done only once when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how valid it is but

```
&#10;
```

in place of the newlines should work.

Comment: Out of interest, how would I do that and what does it do?

Comment: change it to $replace = '&#10;';

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
$str     = $_POST['content'];
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace($order, $replace, $str));
```

with this code :

```
$str     = $_POST['content'];
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br($str));
```